# Javascript - Uncaught TypeError: tri.Area is not a function

Tags: javascript

So i'm starting to learn ab it of JS. This is probably kinda basic since I started with it yesterday. So I have come so far that I actually got a error that I have been trying to figure out this past 2-3 hours without any results.

I'm trying to take the value from height and width where I create a own function (area) that should make a math value from height * width / 2 and then return it back to area(). and then get the value in console.log. Pretty simple but im getting a error on the last console.log for some strange reason which I cant figure out why.

```
function x(a, b) {

    return { 
        a: a, b: b
        }
}

function Area(a, b) { 
    this.a = a; 
    this.b = b; 
    this.y = this.a* this.b / 2; 
    return y; 
}




var Snorlax = x(12, 14);
console.log(Snorlax.a); 
console.log(Snorlax.b); 
console.log(Snorlax.Area());   <---- Issue here
```

What could the issue be?

EDIT: So the issue is that im getting a issue on `console.log(Snorlax.Area());   <---- Issue here` where it says **Snorlax.Area is not a function** so basically I just wanna fix it to make this program to work. By having the  `console.log(Snorlax.Area());` it supposed to make the function Area to work and give me a results of a*b/2. Thats pretty much it.

EDIT2:

function x(a, b) {

```
    return { 
        a: a, b: b
        }
}

function Area(a, b) { 
    return a * b / 2;
}


var Snorlax = x(12, 14);
console.log(Snorlax.a); 
console.log(Snorlax.b); 
console.log(Area(Snorlax.a, Snorlax b));
```

In that case that would be right?

Comment: WHere is `Triangle()` ?

Comment: @tushar I dont know how that came. It was supposed to be a X haha. I think I copy pasted it from somewhere else. But it still the same issue.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Its been a issue with copy pasting sir. The issue isnt that. Im sorry but something happened when I pasted here. It should be right now :)

Comment: `Area` is not a method of `x`.

Comment: `return y;` should be `return this.y` otherwise you'll get a reference error.

Comment: So they somehow need to be combined if thats what you mean?

Comment: I did that but it didnt helped at all :/ Still getting : Snorlax.Area is not a function

Comment: Area has nothing to do with the method x... Just because Area is defined, it is not hooked up to the method.

Comment: `Snorlax.Area` is **not a function**. If you want to use Area in the context of Snorlax you must bind the context, like this `Area.call(Snorlax)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your not passing in `a,b` to the `Area() function`

Try: `console.log(Area(Snorlax.a,Snorlax.b));`

Return `this.y` from the `Area function`

The reason you function is not defined is because you were calling an Area function on your `x` object(which does not exist). You need to call the Area function straight like above.

Comment: There's still the issue of the undefined `y` in the return statement.

Comment: How would that in that case do the math in Area function? I think it that case it would skip it?

Comment: @ThrillOfit - please double check your english, it's hard to know what your asking

Comment: @thrillOfit not sure what your question is?

Comment: Alright, I will do a EDIT. Im sorry for my english, Will try to define it better now. Give me a  minute.

Comment: Hmm, In that case I wouldnt even need the "This" function and just return a*b/2 in that case?

Comment: looks okay. if it works please mark answer as correct